# JestJS: Test for valid timestamp inside of expected object

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I'm trying to test for an expected object via Jest

```
expect(object).toMatchObject({
  content: 'some text',
  timestamp: expect.any(Number)
})
```

This is working so far, but I would like to test if the number is a valid timestamp: `/^(\d{10})?$/`

Not only any number. Maybe there is a better way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would keep your original assertion to check the shape of your object and that the timestamp property is actually a number.

```
expect(object).toMatchObject({
  content: 'some text',
  timestamp: expect.any(Number)
})
```

If you really want to check that timestamp fits your regex then you could always add another assertion in your test where you convert the value to a string (so that you can use the .match() regex function built into javascript) and ensure that it returns true.

```
expect(object.timestamp.toString().match(/^(\d{10})?$/)).toBe(true)
```

Note: you may want to make sure that regex is really checking what you want.